# Is it bad design to have access to the UnitOfWork in the Repository?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, transactions, entity-framework-4.1, unit-of-work

Background: Entity framework4.1 and MVC4

My setup has model entities, and then a generic repository and then model specific repositories like UserRepository, ProductRepository that inherit from the generic repository.

**I then have a service layer that use these repositories along with any business logic, and the UnitOfWork object is accessible here to call Commit.**

With the Unit of work pattern, and my quesiton is:

**Is it poor design to let the repository layer have access to the UnitOfWork object?**

To me this seems to be a 'leak' because now things may be commit when you don't even realize it.

is this correct?

e.g.

```
public class ProductService
{


   public void SaveProduct(Product product)
   {
      try
      {
        productRepository.Save(product);
        statsRepository.Update(product);
        this.UnitOfWork.Commit();
      } catch(..) 
      {
            //
      }
      finally()
      {
        //
      }


   }

}
```

Now if any one of those calls fails, commit won't be called.

But if in the abcRepository layer you had access to the UofW object and called commit, it would behave in a inconsistant manner.

Comment: In my opinion, it should be the responsibility of the thing that created the unit-of-work to be the one who commits.  The repository may not have the entire context of that specific unit-of-work.

Comment: The way I've seen `UnitOfWork` before was the `UnitOfWork` has access to the repository not the other way around.

Comment: @Matthew so that would be in the MVC controller in my case, which I then pass to the ABCService class.

Comment: I think that would make sense, @Charles380 suggestion sounds appropriate to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is the right way of implementing repository and UnitofWork

http://code.cmsstores.com/implementing-unit-of-work-pattern-dot-net/

Answer (score 0):

I think the repository should not access the u-o-w, as *Matthew* already commented. Your question pretty much answers itself.

Re: *Now if any one of those calls fails, commit won't be called.* -

This is, generally, good, right? You don't want to commit your changes partially.